# Tuple and average components

Tags: python, tuples

We have a tuple let say (12,6,3) and we want to calculate the average of its components, in this example we want to have (12+6+3)/3 how do we write this function that returns the result which in this case is 7.

thank you in advance

Comment: What portion of this function have you written so far, and could you post it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built-in statistics module for that:

```py
import statistics

a = (12,6,3)
statistics.mean(a)
```

alternatively, simply calculate the mean by hand:

```
a = (12,6,3)
int(sum(a) / len(a))
```

Comment: @Martin did this help solve it, if so please accept the answer